# propleme with the injection of dependence of spring

Tags: spring

For the project that we create during my formation we use spring to make dependency injection.

we have a servlet-context.xml file with the following configuration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="fr.autoquiz3000" />
```

I created several controllers and I have no problem injecting the dao for example:

```
package fr.autoquiz3000;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/public")
public class PublicController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao uDao;

    @GetMapping("/connection")
    public ModelAndView getConnection() {
        return new ModelAndView("public/viewConnexion");
    }
```

but I try to create a filter with a dao like this:

```
package fr.autoquiz3000;

@Component
public class CountQuizStudent implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    private QuizToDoDao qtdDao;
```

and I have this error:

```
qtdDao= null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at fr.autoquiz3000.CountQuizStudent.doFilter(CountQuizStudent.java:41)
```

Someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong!

thank you!

Comment: Spring can only inject beans in other beans, that it creates and manages. A Filter is not a Spring bean. The servlet container create the filter, not Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For filters override init method and set Spring beans there:

```
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    WebApplicationContext springContext =
        WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(filterConfig.getServletContext());
    userDao = springContext.getBean(UserDao.class);
}
```

or use DelegatingFilterProxy:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>yourFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>yourFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


@Component("yourFilter")
public class YourFilter implements Filter { 
    // auto wiring available as it's just Spring Bean
}
```

Comment: with this changes I get this error message:
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'yourFilter' available
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1205)

Comment: The @Component("yourFilter") should be on your class CountQuizStudent, I just introduced some example naming (you even should change it to countQuizStudentFilter both Java and XML configuration)